# Getting CS1502: The best overloaded method match for <some_method> has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, asmx, vb.net-to-c#

I currently have the following code:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Notifications" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Notification
{
    public int id;
    public string text;

    public Notification(int m_id, string m_text)
    {
        id = m_id;
        text = m_text;
    }

    public Notification() {}
}

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Notifications : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    List<Notification> Notification = new List<Notification>();

    [WebMethod()]
    public List<Notification> GetNotifications()
    {
        var notifications = new List<Notification>();

        using (SqlConnection objSQLConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
        {
            using (SqlCommand objSQLCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where col1 = @user", objSQLConnection))
            {
                objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = "abc";

                objSQLConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader objSQLDataReader = objSQLCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (objSQLDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        notifications.Add(new Notification(objSQLDataReader["id"], objSQLDataReader["text"]));
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return notifications;
    }

}
```

Which is giving me the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Notification.Notification(int, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

On the line:

```
notifications.Add(new Notification(objSQLDataReader["id"], objSQLDataReader["text"]));
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, the human brain. (Or, at least, a good number of human brains here, hopefully...)

Comment: If you don't even know what part of the conversion is broken, maybe you should just stick to VB.

Comment: It would help if you'd specify at least some of the errors that have been given. (There are problems with the code in terms of not using a `using` statement and possibly reusing a shared variable called Notifications instead of creating a new list, but those a problems in the original too...)

Comment: I see that the code is converted right

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. It would be really, really, *really* helpful if you gave us the error message, too!

Comment: Ok. I understand that the line `objSQLConnection = new ...` is giving you a compiler error - but *what is the exact error message*?

Comment: Updated question/code above with the latest code from answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some missing from the function, you never create the Notifications object for example. If you use implicitly created variables in VB, that will most likely not work to convert into C# (and is not encouraged in VB either). Also, I would encourage you to use `Using` blocks to make sure that everything is closed and disposed properly:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetNotifications() As List(Of Notification)
  Dim notifications As New List(Of Notification)()

  Using connection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"))
    Using command = New SqlCommand("select * from table1 where col1 = @user", connection)
      command.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = sUser;

      connection.Open()
      Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()

        Dim idIndex As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("id")
        Dim textIndex As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("text")

        While reader.Read()
          notifications.Add(New Notification(reader.GetInt32(idIndex), reader.GetString(textIndex)))
        End While

      End Using
    End Using
  End Using

  Return notifications
End Function
```

Now it should (ideally) convert into:

```
[WebMethod()]
public List<Notification> GetNotifications() {
  var notifications = new List<Notification>();

  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"])) {
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where col1 = @user", connection)) {
      command.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = sUser;

      connection.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {

        int idIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("id")
        int textIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("text")

        while (reader.Read()) {
          notifications.Add(new Notification(reader.GetInt32(idIndex), reader.GetString(textIndex)));
        }

      }
    }
  }

  return notifications;
}
```

#### Edit:

Changes done:

- Changed to brackets when accessing `AppSettings`
- Changed to brackets when accessinfg `objSQLDataReader`
- Changed reader code to use `GetOrdinal`, `GetInt32` and `GetString`
- Changed variable names; removed hungarian notation

Comment: I should have posted these details before, but to hopefully make up, I have posted it now in the `stuff not shown in original question`, above in the original question.

Comment: @nami: I see. The member variables that you use in the method should actually be local variables instead. They are not used outside the method, so there is no reason to give them page scope.

Comment: @nami: The conversion tool doesn't know that `AppSettings` is a collection instead of a method, so it does't know to convert the parentheses to brackets. I corrected my code above.

Comment: That got much much further, thanks!  I am getting the following error `CS0118: 'objSQLDataReader' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'` on line `notifications.Add(new Notification(objSQLDataReader("id"), objSQLDataReader("text")));`

Comment: @nami: Ah, basically the same thing. The converter doesn't know that you are using the indexer of the data reader. I corrected my code above again. :)

Comment: done, but now I am getting `The best overloaded method match for 'Notification.Notification(int, string)' has some invalid arguments` on the same line.  Seem so close yet so far.

Comment: @nami: It's the implicit conversions in VB, you should use `Option Strict` in VB so that there is no implicit conversions. The data reader indexer returns the values as `object`, so casting them to `int` and `string` would work, but I changed the code to use the `GetInt32` and `GetString` methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help!  So C# does Strict conversions by default, assuming there is no option strict in c#?

Comment: @nami: Yes, there is only strict conversion rules in C#, so there is no option for that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously the code was correctly converted - only the variables used have not been declared in VB, so they are also not declared in the C# code. The following should work better:

```
[WebMethod()]
public List<Notification> GetNotifications()
{
    // Have a look at the code conventions - variable names should not start
    // with a capital letter...
    List<Notification> Notifications = new List<Notification>();

    SqlConnection objSQLConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"));

    SqlCommand objSQLCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table1 where col1 = @user", objSQLConnection);
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = sUser;

    objSQLCommand.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader objSQLDataReader = objSQLCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (objSQLDataReader.Read()) {
        Notifications.Add(new Notification(objSQLDataReader("id"), objSQLDataReader("text")));
    }

    objSQLDataReader.Close();
    objSQLCommand.Connection.Close();

    return Notifications;
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to add the respective `using` statements!

**EDIT**
Made another change to the code - `Notifications` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Please see `stuff not shown in original question`, above in the original question.

Comment: Updated question/code above with the latest code from answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is vb code accesses `AppSettings` (and arrays in general) like:

```
AppSettings("keyname")
```

and c# does arrays as:

```
AppSettings["keyname"]
```

The converter sometimes has trouble telling the difference between an array and a function.

Comment: Updated question/code above with the latest code from answers.

Answer (score 0):

DevelopFusion's VB to C# converter (and others) is a free service, provided at no cost to you. It is a ***guide***. Most of the code you've presented is functional, and you only now need to spend a tenth of them time correcting a few small issues with your code (the code above is syntactically correct, by the way... if you've declared the undeclared variables *hint*). Specifically, you need to declare `objSQLCommand` and `objSQLDataReader` if you haven't already done so elsewhere:

```
SqlCommand objSQLCommand;
SqlDataReader objSQLDataReader;
```

Comment: I declared those above the shown code as follows:    `SqlConnection objSQLConnection = SqlConnection;
    SqlCommand objSQLCommand = SqlCommand;
    SqlDataReader objSQLDataReader = SqlDataReader;`

Comment: Just add the code snippet above just after the function definition (so the line right after `public List<Notification> GetNotifications(){`, and after the brace.

Comment: @nami: Those declarations do not make any sense and are in any case syntactically wrong, they shouldn't even compile. Try: `SqlConnection objSQLConnection = null` or `SqlConnection objSQLConnection;` would do as you are assigning variables before they are used.

Comment: It was what I was given from the developer fusion converter.  Anyway, I've updated the question with the full converted code.

Comment: Updated question/code above with the latest code from answers.